# Plotting Repeating Data Set from File using matplotlib and lists

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, physics

this is my first post here, so I hope it goes well.

I have a file of data(about 2mb) in the format
angle (space) energy (space) counts
angle (space) energy (space) counts
angle (space) energy (space) counts, etc.

(this is data recorded from a particle accelerator running for ~170 hours, so the file is large)

Angle starts out at 0, and is 0 while energy goes up to about 4500, and then
angle increases by one and energy starts again at 0 and goes up to 4500. This repeats
until theta = 255.

I am trying to create a program that plots the number of counts versus the energy level, energy level being my x axis, and counts being my y axis. I have tried many solutions, but to no avail.

Any help given to me on this would be much appreciated.

My code is posted below.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pylab
    from numpy import *
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    import math
    import sys
    import scipy.optimize
    """
    Usage
    ---------------
    Takes a file in the format of
    Theta |Rel_MeV |Counts
    97  4024    0
    97  4025    0
    97  4026    6
    97  4027    2

    and graphs it

    fileURL is the input for the file to put into the program
    txt_Title is the graph label
    """
    DEBUG = 1
    fileURL = './ne19_peaks_all.dat'
    txt_Title = 'Oxygen and Alpha Particle Relative Energy'
    MeV_divide_factor = 100
    ptSize = 5
    MarkerType = '+'
    MeV_max = 5000

    def main():
    # Read the file.
        f2 = open(fileURL, 'r')
        # read the whole file into a single variable, which is a list of every row of the file.
        lines = f2.readlines()
        f2.close()

        # initialize some variable to be lists:
        list_MeV = []
        list_counts = []
        for i in range(MeV_max):
            list_MeV.append(i)
            list_counts.append(0)

        # scan the rows of the file stored in lines, and put the values into some variables:
        for line in lines:
            p = line.split()
            MeV = float(p[1])/MeV_divide_factor
            count = float(p[2])
            list_counts[int(MeV)] += count

        x_arr = np.array(list_MeV)
        y_arr = np.array(list_counts)

        plt.plot(x_arr, y_arr, MarkerType)
        plt.title(txt_Title)
        plt.show()
        return 0

    def func(x, a, b):
        return a*x + b

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        status = main()
        sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? I can see only one error - `MeV_max` should be 50 instead of 5000

Comment: I actually figured out a solution to my problem, ended up using a dictionary where each energy level was a key, and with the counts being the values

Answer (score 0):

Used a dictionary where each energy level was a key, and with the counts being the values